# Stein-chen's characterization for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I've been asked that if a **real-valued** random variable $X$ satisfies that for any $f\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})=\{\text{smooth functions with compact support}\}$ one has $\mathbb{E}(f(X+1))=\mathbb{E}(Xf(X))$, then $X$ follows the Poisson($1$) distribution.

I know how to prove this if we assume $X$ is non-negative integer valued and we require $f$ to be bounded rather than smooth. Indeed, for each $A\subset\mathbb{Z}^+$, the equation $f(x+1)-xf(x)=1_{A}(x)-\sum_{k\in A}e^{-1}\frac{1}{k!}$ (here $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$) has a unique solution $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the initial value $f(0)=0$, and this solution is bounded. Then the condition applies to $f$ and thus $P(X\in A)=\sum_{k\in A}e^{-1}\frac{1}{k!}$, which gives the desired conclusion.

However, I can not figure out how this approach (which is standard for this type of question) extends to the problem I've encountered. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $X$. Then your equation is $\mu(x - 1) = x\mu(x)$ in the sense of distributions. By taking the characteristic function of both sides, you can eventually arrive at an ODE for the characteristic function $\tilde{\mu}(t)$ for which the only solution is the poisson characteristic function.

Comment: @Mason Do you mean that $\mu(B)=P(X\in B)$ for $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu(x)=\mu(\{x\})$? If so, then I don't think this equation implies that $\mu$ is the law of Poisson distribution, since for any probability measure $\mu$ with no atom, $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus the equation you've mentioned always holds.

Comment: No, here $\mu(x)$ denotes the tempered distribution $\mu$. I mean equality in the sense of tempered distributions. So if $\mu$ has a density $f$, then the density $f$ satisfies $f(x - 1) = xf(x)$, but the equation I wrote makes sense for all tempered distributions $\mu$. My argument shows that the only tempered distribution solving the equation is the Poisson 1 measure.

Comment: My argument amounts to plugging in $f(x) = e^{itx}$.

Comment: Ok I partially understand since I am not familiar with the distributions:(. But why can we plug in $f(x)=e^{itx}$ (which is not compactly supported)? What if $\int f(x)x\mu(dx)$  is not defined, i.e. the function $xf(x)$  is not $\mu$ integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $X$. Then we have
$$E(f(X + 1)) = \langle f(x + 1), \mu(x)\rangle_{x} = \langle f(x), \mu(x - 1)\rangle_{x}$$
and
$$E(Xf(X)) = \langle xf(x), \mu(x)\rangle_{x} = \langle f(x), x\mu(x)\rangle_{x}.$$
Here $\langle g, T\rangle = T(g)$ is the pairing of compactly supported smooth functions $g$ and distributions $T$. Thus we have the equation
$$\mu(x - 1) = x\mu(x).$$
Let $\phi(t) = \int e^{itx}\mu(dx)$ be the characteristic function of $\mu$. Take the characteristic function of both sides to get the following equality of tempered distributions:
$$e^{it}\phi(t) = \frac{1}{i}\phi'(t).$$
Hence
$$\phi'(t) = ie^{it}\phi(t).$$
Since $\mu$ is a probability measure, the right hand side is a continuous function, so $\phi'$ is continuous, so $\phi$ is a $C^1$ function. Moreover $\phi(0) = 1$. We have
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = ie^{it}\phi,$$
$$\frac{1}{\phi}\,d\phi = ie^{it}dt,$$
$$\log(\phi) = e^{it} + C,$$
$$\phi = C\exp(e^{it}),$$
$$\phi = \exp(e^{it} - 1).$$
Hence $\phi(t) = \exp(e^{it} - 1)$, which is the characteristic function of Poisson(1).

If you didn't know the Poisson characteristic function, you can note that $\phi$ is $2\pi$ periodic, which implies by Fourier inversion that $\mu$ is supported on the Integers with
$$\mu(j) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-itj}\phi(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-itj}\exp(e^{it} - 1)\,dt.$$
The integral will evaluate to the Poisson PMF.

Comment: Why is the function $\phi$   differentiable? I comprehend the equation of distributions as an equation of linear functional on the class of smooth functions with compact supports, so why it applies to $f(x)=e^{itx}$? (I  am not familiar with the distributions so maybe I made some mistakes :(.

Comment: You can always form the derivative of a distribution $T$ by $\langle g, T' \rangle := -\langle g', T \rangle$. The proof showed that the distributional derivative of $\phi$ is actually a continuous function, so it follows from distribution theory that $\phi$ is $C^1$ in the usual sense.

Comment: I am not using $f(x) = e^{itx}$. I am letting $f$ be any $C_c^{\infty}$ function.

Comment: For the second question, I mean we have $\int f(x+1)\mu(dx)=\int f(x)x\mu(dx)$ for any $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$, then why do we have $\int e^{it(x+1)}\mu(dx)=\int e^{itx}x\mu(dx)$? Is the integral of $e^{itx}x$ with respect to $\mu$ well-defined? Besides, what's the meaning of a characteristic function to be a distribution?

Comment: I didn't claim that we have $\int e^{it(x + 1)}\mu(dx) = \int e^{itx}x\mu(dx)$. From $\int f(x + 1)\mu(dx) = \int f(x)x\mu(dx)$ we have trivially that $\mu(x - 1)$ and $x\mu(x)$ are equal as distributions. Now just as you can naturally define the Fourier transform of any tempered distribution by $\langle f, \hat{T} \rangle := \langle \hat{f}, T \rangle$, you can naturally define the characteristic function by $\langle f, \phi_T \rangle := \langle \phi_f, T \rangle$. The characteristic function is the inverse Fourier transform. So the characteristic functions $\mu(x - 1)$ and $x\mu(x)$ are equa

Comment: Ah I see how it works as distributions. Do you have any recommended reference for tempered distributions?

Comment: @INvisibLE A good introduction to distributions is "Introduction to
the theory of distributions" by Friedlander and Joshi. Also "Real Analysis" by Folland covers them.